# Bash Linux права доступа

Tags: linux, bash, права-доступа

как настроить директорию так, что бы любой файл создаваемый в ней пользователем или группой, автоматически присваивался группе?

Comment: Ээээ... `chown`, `umask`?

Answer (score 1):

Смотря где вы это делаете.
Если в консоли, то вам поможет SGUID установленный на папке. В этой папке при создании файлов, они будут создаваться с владельце группы.

```bsh
cd /tmp/
mkdir test
cd test
sudo chown user:new_group
sudo chmod g+s .
touch test
```

файл тест будет создан с группой new_group